# Preventing Unhandled promise rejection using Sendgrid/mail and nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sendgrid

I don't receive my emails at all and I receive an error in the terminal of processTicksAndRejections. Im not sure if i have to add an async to my function to handle the error. I also tried clearing my npm cache and I had no changes to my errors. My email is getting rejected and i have cloudinary attched and I can see my images in cloudinary dashboard when i upload but I dont recieve an email of images and form sent to my email.

controllers/feedback.js

```
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

exports.emailFeedback = (req, res) => {
  // console.log(req.body);
  const { name, email, message, phone, uploadedFiles } = req.body;
  const emailData = {
    to: process.env.EMAIL_TO,
    from: email,
    subject: "Feedback form",
    html: `
            <h1>Customer Feedback Form</h1>
            <hr />
            <h2>Sender name: ${name}</h2>
            <h2>Sender email: ${email}</h2>
            <h2>Sender message: ${message}</h2>
            <br />
            ${uploadedFiles.map((f) => {
              return `<img src="${f.secure_url}" alt="${f.original_filename}" style="width:50%;overflow:hidden;padding:50px;" />`;
            })}
            <hr />
            <p>https://feedbackonline.com</p>
        `,
  };

  sgMail
    .send(emailData)
    .then((sent) => {
      console.log(sent);
      return res.json({
        success: true,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      return res.json({
        success: false,
      });
    });
};
```

I get an error in localhost of Cannot GET /api when I change my call from get to a post.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by creating a email Sender Verification by adding my email address that I want to send my replies.

// This test works

```
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");

const API_KEY =
  "";

sgMail.setApiKey(API_KEY);

const message = {
  to: "zilahmusicpub@outlook.com",
  from: "tailoredr@mail.com",
  subject: "Hello from sendgrid",
  text: "Hello from sendgrid",
  html: "<h1>Hello from sendgrid to outlook</h1>",
};

sgMail
  .send(message)
  .then((response) => console.log("Email sent..."))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `return` before the `sqMail` (to make it so the node engine 'waits' for the async result)

```js
return sgMail
    .send(emailData)
    .then((sent) => {
```

And improve your error handler like so:

```js
      return res
        .status(500)
        .json({
          error: err.message,
          success: false,
        });
```

That should shed more light on the exact issue.

Comment: I now receive statusCode: 202 The email is being sent but it is not being recieved.

Comment: Is it showing up in the sendgrid dashboard?

Comment: I solved this problem by creating a email Sender Verification.